# Read HTML snippet from DOM and add custom data to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, foreach

I'm used to use jQuery to query elements by their id and place inside them or in their attributes some custom data retrieved from a webservice.

But now the data I'll retrieve is an array of objects. So it's not just a matter of adding one data into one element. I need to read a `li` which has some HTML inside, then replace some elements on this HTML with data from one object.

This has to be done for each object in the array, so I'd need to create a new `li` from that "template", populate it, then add it to the `ul`.

I'm able to query the `ul`, find its `li` and remove it from DOM, and append multiple `li`s to it.

But I don't know how, having the `li` in a jQuery object, make changes on its innerHTML. This is the part I'm lost, as I was still unable to find some solution on Google.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/r76vpLdg/

How can I create a new object based on `template` and replace the contents of those 2 `span`s? I added a second list, with an example of the desired result.

Comment: Looks like you're just looking for this: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements "in memory" without them being part of the DOM, build them up, then add them to the DOM as required, eg:

```
 var li = `$("<li>"); 
 li.html(innerHTML); 
 ul.append(li);
```

Working example:

```js
var ul = $("ul");

$("button").click(function() {
  var li = $("<li>");
  li.text("new item");

  ul.append(li);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
<button type='button'>add</button>
```

To work with an existing "template", you can `.clone()` an existing `li` and make changes, one possible solution/example:

```js
var ul = $("ul");

$("button").click(function() {
  // create a copy of the "template"
  var li = ul.find("li.template").clone().removeClass("template");  
  
  // make changes 
  li.find("span").removeClass("first").addClass("new").text("new");

  ul.append(li);
});
```

```css
li>span.first { color: blue; }
li>span.new  { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class='template'>This is the <span class='first'>first</span> item</li>
</ul> 
<hr/>
<button type='button'>add</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the easy part, removing and adding elements to ul. What I can't figure out is how to clone the template and change values on its spans.

Comment: I can't just create new basic `li`s, because I need to change its spans values, for each object on the webservice's list.

Comment: From your other comment, assuming the "template" can be quite large, you'll want to `.clone` the template then make changes to that copy.  Updated with an example.

Comment: Essentially, it works exactly the same way - the variable will store a reference to an in-memory element rather than to one that's already in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Vanilla JS solution using a JSON object as data source and template strings.

Unless using jQuery is a must, there is no reason to use it in this case.

```
<p>template:</p>
<ul id="myListContainer">

</ul>

<button onclick="createTemplateStrings()">
START
</button>
```

```
function createTemplateStrings (){

var obj = [
{"name": "John", "weekday" : "Wednesday"},
{"name": "Marry", "weekday" : "Sunday"},
{"name": "Edward", "weekday" : "Friday"},
{"name": "Jack", "weekday" : "Tuesday"}
]

let ul = document.getElementById('myListContainer')

for(let row of obj){

let li = document.createElement('LI')
li.innerHTML = `Hello, ${row.name}, how's your ${row.weekday} ?`
ul.append(li)

}


}
```

Comment: Thanks! So, I can't read the `li`'s HTML from DOM, I must have it fully inside javascript? It will be a very big HTML and have around 4 `span`s to be customized, so I wanted to avoid having the full inner HTML in javascript.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean ? Do you have 4 static LIs and want to change the InnerHTML ? Why not simply give them IDs and change the innerHtml ?

Comment: I'm sorry. In the example, I have a template li with 2 spans inside its inner HTML. I need to change these spans' values with an object's attributes.